# Bulk insert CSV file from Azure blob storage to SQL managed instance

Tags: sql-server, azure, csv, bulkinsert

I have CSV file on Azure blob storage. It has 4 columns in it without headers and one blank row at starting. I am inserting CSV file into SQL managed instance by `bulkinsert` and I have 5 columns in the database table. I don't have 5th column in CSV file.

Therefore it is throwing this error:

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 5 (uId2)

As I want to insert that 4 columns from CSV file to table in database and I want that 5th column in table as NULL.

I am using this code:

```
BULK INSERT testing
FROM 'test.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'BULKTEST',
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  FIRSTROW = 0,
  CODEPAGE = '65001',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
   );
```

Want that 5th row as `NULL` in database table, if there are 4 columns in `CSV` file.

Comment: Hi Dipesh Pawar, If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, we achieve that in bulk insert. None of other ways according my experience.

Azure SQL managed instance is also not supported as dataset in Data Factory [Data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview). Otherwise  we can using Data Flow [derived column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) to create a new column to mapping to the Azure SQL database.

The best way is that you editor your csv file: just add new column as header in you csv files.

Hope this helps.